# How to change AWS Lamp apache root directory?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, apache, lamp

I am using `AWS Lamp apache` service. Here `htdocs` folder is the default root directory. I have a folder named `my-folder` inside `htdocs`.

```
htdocs
  my-folder
```

I want to set `my-folder` as a root directory.

**But How?**

I have edited `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf`
Here are the edited codes in `httpd.conf` file.

```
# DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
# <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">

DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/my-folder"
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/my-folder">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**But it doesn't work!**

**Please correct me.**

Comment: Are you using `EC2` or `Lighthouse`?

Comment: Lightsail bro and problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

I just modified `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/00_status-vhost.conf` as below.

```
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/my-folder
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/my-folder">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>

   #for https
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/my-folder
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
   <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/my-folder">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

**and it's working!**

Documention provided by `AWS` [Create A Virtual Host For A Custom Application](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/configuration/configure-custom-application/)

Comment: A couple years later on and I'm finding this very helpful, but wanted to leave a note on what's changed. When you get into the `vhosts` directory, there will be two sample files that you can copy out of and use to create the above code. You'll want to modify the ServerName and DocumentRoot for both, and the SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile will need updated to your keys, likely in `/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates`. (These files were autogenned for me during installation of the AWS AMI for Bitnami, your mileage may vary)